# AngularJS editable-text - disable button if validation failes

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I use AngularJSs editable-text to make things changeable. My question now would be it there is a possibility to disable the confirmation while data-e-ng-change is false?

```
<span editable-text="vm.foundedUser.username" data-e-ng-change="vm.checkUsername($data)" onbeforesave="vm.checkUsername($data)" onaftersave="vm.updateUser()">
    {{vm.foundedUser.username || '--'}}
</span>
```

My checkUsername function looks like this:

```
function checkUsername(username) {
        if(username.length < 5) {
            return false;
        }
        validateService.checkUniqueUsername(username).success(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        }).error(function(e){
              console.log('error in management.controller.js#checkUsername');
        });
    }
```

but it does not work, I guess because validateService.checkUniqueUsername is asynchron but I still dont know.

Comment: `<button type="submit" ng-disabled="vm.foundedUser.username.$pristine">Submit</button >`  . This utilizes Angular's built-in input-state modifiers to detect when the field has been changed.modified.

Comment: I can not do it, is there an exampel showing this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`<button type="submit" ng-disabled="vm.checkUsername($data)"> Submit </button>`